# Stripe effect in formattable(), shadow in light gray every other row. R

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, htmlwidgets, formattable

I was wondering, does anyone know how to achieve the "stripe" style seen in kableExtra? That is to shadow in light gray odd rows but not even rows? Something like the following picture:

[image]

Given my code using formattable, I am going to export the table to a pdf document, so I would like to know If I can achieve that effect? is it possible? I tried modifying td's, tr's but the actual cells were very strangely shaded creating an undesired effect. This is the current code I got and its output:

```
library("htmltools")
library("webshot")  
library(formattable)
DF <- data.frame(Ticker=c("", "", "", "IBM", "AAPL", "MSFT"),
                 Name=c("Dow Jones", "S&P 500", "Technology", 
                        "IBM", "Apple", "Microsoft"),
                 Value=accounting(c(15988.08, 1880.33, 50, 
                                    130.00, 97.05, 50.99)),
                 Change=percent(c(-0.0239, -0.0216, 0.021, 
                                  -0.0219, -0.0248, -0.0399)))

################################## FUNCTIONS ##################################
unit.scale = function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
export_formattable <- function(f, file, width = "100%", height = NULL, 
                               background = "white", delay = 0.2)
    {
      w <- as.htmlwidget(f, width = width, height = height)
      #Remove row height!
      w <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(w, tags$style("td { padding: 0px  !Important;}"))
      path <- html_print(w, background = background, viewer = NULL)
      url <- paste0("file:///", gsub("\\\\", "/", normalizePath(path)))
      webshot(url,
              file = file,
              selector = ".formattable_widget",
              delay = delay)
    }
###############################################################################

FT <- formattable(DF, align =c("l","c","r","c"), list(
  Name=formatter("span", 
                 style = x ~ ifelse(x == "Technology", style(font.weight = "bold"), NA)), #NOT APPLIED when we output to PNG with the function!
  #Value = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  Value = color_bar("orange" , fun = unit.scale
                    ),
  Change = formatter("span", 
                     style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0 , "red", "green"), "font.size" = "18px"), 
                     x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), x)
                     )),
  table.attr = 'style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Calibri";\"')

FT
#OUTPUT the table in the document as an image!
export_formattable(FT,"/outputpath/FT.png")
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.table-striped` inside the `table.attr` argument to add zebra-striping to any table row.

**Code**

```
FT <- formattable(DF, align =c("l","c","r","c"), list(
  Name=formatter("span", 
                 style = x ~ ifelse(x == "Technology", style(font.weight = "bold"), NA)), #NOT APPLIED when we output to PNG with the function!
  #Value = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  Value = color_bar("orange" , fun = unit.scale
  ),
  Change = formatter("span", 
                     style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0 , "red", "green"), "font.size" = "18px"), 
                     x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), x)
  )),
  table.attr = 'class=\"table table-striped\" style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Calibri"')
```

**Table**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Follow up question. How would I change the default background color from this super light gray to red or blue or any other hexadecimal color? Thanks!